# How to get row data as columns in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to write a query to get row data as columns. I have this join between 2 tables.

Example:

```
ID | Manager| Property| Value
--------------------------
1  | John   | Salary  | 300000
1  | John   | Age     | 42
1  | John   | Dept    | IT
```

and so on. The properties for the managers should all come in the same row so instead of having 3 rows here I need the data like

```
ID | Manager | Salary | Age | Dept
-----------------------------------
1  | John    | 300000 | 42  | IT
```

Can we do this in SQL directly?

Comment: google for `sql pivot`

Comment: depends on which RDBMS you're using. MySQL does not have a PIVOT function, but I think PostgreSQL, SQL Server and Oracle do. Remember: SQL is implemented differently by each vendor, and AFAIK PIVOT is not part of SQL standard

Comment: Johnny I saw your other note and have updated the PIVOT answer I provided to show you how you can use the inner join between the 2 tables within a PIVOT Query. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comment on other answer if 2 tables that is no problem just do a Join in your initial select.  in SQL 2012 Pivot is a nice feature available to you.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
       m.Id
       ,m.Manager
       ,a.Property
       ,a.Value
    FROM
       Managers m
       INNER JOIN Attributes a
       ON m.Id = a.Id
       ) t
    PIVOT
       (
          MAX(Value)
          FOR Property IN ([Salary],[Age],[Dept])
       ) AS p
```

And using PIVOT if available within RDBMS

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM TableName) t
    PIVOT
       (
          MAX(Value)
          FOR Property IN ([Salary],[Age],[Dept])
       ) AS p
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked just the way I wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome, @TimeBiegeleisen 's method is a good one to keep in your back pocket if you do a lot of pivot as it is essentially what the database engine's do with a PIVOT query.

Answer (score 2):

You never told us which version of SQL you are using, but the following pivot query should work across most RDBMS:

```
SELECT ID, Manager,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Property = 'Salary' THEN Salary ELSE NULL END) AS Salary,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Property = 'Age'    THEN Age    ELSE NULL END) AS Age,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Property = 'Dept'   THEN Dept   ELSE NULL END) AS Dept
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID, Manager
```

This solution relies on a trick, namely the assumption that the `MAX` function ignores `NULL` values, which is true for MySQL, Oracle, and SQL Server.

Comment: I am sorry I am using SQL Server 2012. Also the columns ID and Manager are coming from one table and the other 2 columns from a different table. Let me see if I can use your query to get what I want. Thanks.